# WordPress Theme from scratch, widgets don't work

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I know this topic has been discussed quite a bit but I've tried everything I can find online and nothing is working. I need a single widget area in my custom template. I wrote if from scratch and didn't use a barebones type starter therefore I didn't have a functions.php to start from.

In wp-admin it shows my widget as it should but when there is a widget in that area and the page is reloaded it resets. in other words the widget doesn't persist in the area it's supposed to. am I missing something? is my wordpress install bad?

here is my functions.php in it's entirety

```
<?php
register_sidebar
    (
        array(
            'name' => 'Header Widget',
        'id' => 'headerBanner',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="banner">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    )
)
```

?>

and my index.php

```
<?php if ( !dynamic_sidebar (1)) : ?>
<h1>it didn't work</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
<?php if(!dynamic_sidebar ('headerBanner')) : ?>
<h1>it doesn't work</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You need to pass the id of the sidebar you want to display when calling `dynamic_sidebar`

Also note that `dynamic_sidebar` will return false if there are no widgets added to the sidebar so add a widget to it and see if it works

Comment: Thanks Omar but I've tried that before. I just tried it again. Same result, the call to dynamic_sidebar returns false

Comment: Also note that `dynamic_sidebar` will return false if there are no widgets added to the sidebar

Comment: That is definitely the issue then for it returning false. The widgets in wp-admin appear as they should but when there is an active widget dragged inside of one it doesn't persist. if I navigate away from the widgets page in wp-admin and come back it resets.

Comment: Try dragging the native text widget to your sidebar and see if it stays. If it does stay then that means there is a php error causing the widget not to stick.

Comment: what kind of php errors would cause it? what are the common fixes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this other approach?

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'headerBanner' ); ?>
```